# How safe / sanitized is wp_insert_posts()?

Tags: security, sanitization

Looking at the Codex for [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) it states that this function "...sanitizes variables, does some checks, fills in missing variables like date/time, etc. " (EDIT: I [updated the Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Security) to include a more robust example that includes security as well as post meta and category assignment)

Just wondering whether I need to do any further sanitization to prevent XSS hacks and the like or whether enough is being done through the function.

To be honest, I've checked through the function in core and haven't found any wp_kses() or other sanitization on post_content for example, so I'm a little concerned. All I can see that it does is stripslashes_deep() on the data.

So should I be running wp_kses() or anything else when I build my arguments to wp_insert_post()?

What's the best practice here? The Codex is pretty cavalier about security in its example.

Thanks

Comment: It only prevents SQL injection. If you want to run kses on the content, you'll have to do it yourself. WP can't guess what HTML to strip out. What if the post is submitted by an admin, and he wants to insert a `<script>` inside it?

Comment: Okay, good to know. wp_kses_post() on everything then and wp_kses_title() on the title!

Comment: Updated the Codex to show an example of data validation and wp_insert_posts().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to do anything.

On WP load:

`'init' hook -> kses_init() -> kses_init_filters()`

Later:

`wp_insert_post() -> sanitize_post() -> sanitize_post_field() -> 'content_save_pre' -> wp_filter_post_kses()`

Similarly for post titles, comment text etc.

Conclusion: wp_insert_post() is very sanitized. :)

Comment: Thanks Scribu for that correction - definitely a better way to go! Though I wish you hadn't scrapped that entire code snippet, because it was also a good illustration of other aspects of using wp_insert_post() that the main example doesn't cover.

Comment: Yeah, felt kind of bad about that too. However, it was beyond the scope of wp_insert_post(). A separate, top-to-bottom tutorial would be better, I think.

Comment: Updated answer and codex as well.

Comment: lol @ latest edit. sometimes it takes some digging to find all the gold already buried inside core :) I lost the thread when I was tracing it back. Looks like you're a better sleuth than I! Thanks for sticking with this, and updating the codex.